# Windows Virtual Accounts to run desktop applications

Tags: powershell

I recently came across an interesting feature of Windows PowerShell JEA (Just Enough Administration) which by default makes use of Windows virtual accounts to run the remote end point in admin context. I also understand these virtual accounts are created ephemeral for that session and get destroyed when the session ends. This also by default has the local admin rights on the machine for that session while the user running the session is a standard user who can carry out privileged operations using that virtual admin account.

This got me into thinking - we have a few apps in our organisation which sadly need local admin rights to run. We are reluctantly granting admin rights for the users of those apps. So I was wondering if there is a way through PowerShell we can create this Virtual account for the duration of however long that application runs? What I am thinking is some sort of wrapper PowerShell which is targeted by the application shortcut which would internally first spin up this virtual account to run that app as? I am assuming we need to configure some sort of one-off constrained custom app-specific JEA endpoint during the installation of the application. Then again, if the app requires the launching user's context to access back-end database etc. I am not sure how that would be taken into account.

I was just wondering if you have any clever thoughts? Thanks, Steve

Comment: Everything you need can be done yes. You would need to write PS code specifically for it though as there are restrictions on what's available and how. See here for some more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-6

Comment: I wrote a simple JEA role capability file (notepad.exe) and powershell remote endpoint config file and registered the end point. When I launch notepad as the standard configured user, it does not show up (the invoke-command halts) but i can see the virtual account has launched notepad in taskmgr. How to I make it interactive? Doc says wsman session is not designed for GUI-type apps.